# AngularAuth / Firebase - Invalid Email on login screen in Firefox

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm using angular and firebase to sign into my firebase web app. When using Firefox, I briefly get the error:

> auth/invalid-email / The email address is badly formatted.

However, the username and password are correct and I get correctly routed to the signed in app.

**HTML**

```
 <form *ngIf="authService.showLogin" #loginForm="ngForm" action="" (submit)="login()" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
    <h1> Sign In </h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <label> Email Address </label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="name@company.com" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email"
          required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password"
          required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="authService.incorrectPassword">
      <span class="error__msg">{{ authService.incorrectPassword }}</span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()"> Sign In </button>

  </form>



...
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
...

login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

  this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(value => {

    if (this.stateURL != undefined) {
      this.router.navigate([this.stateURL]);
      return Observable.of(true);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['folders']);
      return Observable.of(true);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // console.log(err['code']);
    var errorCode = err.code;
    var errorMessage = err.message;
    console.log(errorCode + ' / ' + errorMessage);
    this.incorrectPassword = ErroAuthEn.convertMessage(err['code']);
    return Observable.of(false);
  });

return;
}
```

As I log my errors to the UI to inform the user, this one is a tad annoying because I briefly see the error before being correctly signed in.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Show the html for the email input.

Comment: Added into the top of the code segment :)

Comment: I don't get it, is `The email address is badly formatted.` from Firebase itself? Or is that one of your custom errors?

Comment: Right now you bind the error to `incorrectPassword` even if that is not what the error says. Also if there is an error your `.then` shouldn't run at all. But from what you're saying both the resolve and reject callbacks run?

Comment: Hi Chrillewoodz. I've updated the code in the 'catch'. console.log(errorCode + ' / ' + errorMessage);. I've also updated the error quote. Yup, so it successfully logs me in AND fires the error log to the console. This doesn't happen in chrome or safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark on this one and say that this is most likely your issue:

```
<form *ngIf="authService.showLogin" #loginForm="ngForm" action="" (submit)="login()" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
```

You are using both Angulars way of writing a form and not.

What it should look like:

```
<form *ngIf="authService.showLogin" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login()" autocomplete="off" novalidate">
```

Here I've removed `action` and `method` as well as swapped `submit` for `ngSubmit`. See if this helps the issue.

Also I found that you are running `login` twice, remove this:

`(click)="login()"` from the submit button.

Comment: Mate, that's brilliant thank you. It was the (click)="login()". I thought I needed to handle both the click on the button and the user hitting enter within the password field independently with the login function. That's brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)